# Make number of matches required directly corresponds with char_length of column

Tags: php, mysql, database, string-length

I have a working SELECT statement. However, I would like to add something to it. I would like to make it so that the number of matches required, directly corresponds with the char_length of the column 'input'. So, for example:

```
if (char_length(input) <= 5) { matches required is 1 }
if (char_length(input) > 5 && char_length(input) <= 10) { matches required is 2 }
if (char_length(input) > 10 && char_length(input) <= 15) { matches required is 3 }

and ect...
```

**How do I add ^^^that to the SELECT statement below?**

```
$text = "one";
$textLen = strlen($text);

SELECT response, ( input LIKE  '% $text %' ) as matches
FROM allData
WHERE (char_length(input) >= '$textLen'-($textLen*.1) 
AND char_length(input) <= '$textLen'+($textLen*.1)) 
HAVING matches > 0 
AND matches = (select max(( input LIKE  '% $text %' )) from allData) limit 30;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following query separately first:

```
SELECT @limit := 0;
```

Then modify your query to look like this:

```
SELECT response, ( input LIKE  '% $text %' ) as matches, @limit := @limit + 1
FROM allData
WHERE (char_length(input) >= '$textLen'-($textLen*.1) 
AND char_length(input) <= '$textLen'+($textLen*.1)) 
AND @limit < CEIL(CHAR_LENGTH(input) / 5)
HAVING matches > 0 
AND matches = (select max(( input LIKE  '% $text %' )) from allData) limit 30;
```

That should limit your matches to the needed values

Comment: It doesn't work. It works the same way as before, without the additional changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704222/selecting-matches-according-to-the-char-length-of-the-strings-in-rows?noredirect=1#comment53253000_32704222 Please take a look at this question. I've re-asked this question with your example, and added a lot more details.