# selecting matches according to the char length of the strings in rows

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database

I have 2 SELECT statements that is suppose to make it so that the number of matches required, directly corresponds with the char_length of the column 'input'. So, for example:

```
if (char_length(input) <= 5) { matches required is 1 }
if (char_length(input) > 5 && char_length(input) <= 10) { matches required is 2 }
if (char_length(input) > 10 && char_length(input) <= 15) { matches required is 3 }

and ect...
```

However, it doesn't. It selects the row as long as there is a match, no matter the length of chars in the string. Here's my code:

```
SELECT @limit :=0;
SELECT input, response, (
input LIKE  '% one %'
) AS matches, @limit := @limit +1
FROM allData
WHERE @limit < CEIL( CHAR_LENGTH( input ) /5 ) 
HAVING matches >0
AND matches = ( 
SELECT MAX( (
input LIKE  '% one %'
) ) 
FROM allData ) 
LIMIT 30 ;
```

So for example:

**Column: input: example row**  `"what superpower would you have for one day"`

^---this would only get selected if there are 8 matches, because 42/5 = 8.4.

42 is the char length of the string above. This should've only been selected from there if there are 8 matches. However, there was only 1 match - the word "one", and yet it was selected anyway. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look at my code.

Got marked duplicate. It's not duplicate. It where I got the answer that doesn't work from.

Comment: @barmar That's where I got my answer from...It doesn't work. That's why I'm re-posting it.

Comment: Why don't you just tell the person who posted the answer that it doesn't work, and resolve it there?

Comment: @Barmar you have 200k rep. You certainly can answer it. can't you?

Comment: I might be able to, but I haven't even thought much about it.

Comment: @Barmar Will you? Please?

Comment: @Barmar I thought it worked at first, but after multiple testing, I found out it didn't.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle to test with?

Comment: @Barmar I have already unaccepted the answer there.

Comment: @Barmar I have made a sqlFiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52ca5c/1 Please take a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by the number of matches? What matches are you counting?

Comment: @Barmar It search for the word "one" in the database, and see how many instances of the word "one" is in the database. If there's 1 "one", the match is 1, and if there's 2 "one", the match is 2.

Comment: So a row with "x one x one x one" would return 3 matches.

Comment: It looks like `@limit < CEIL( CHAR_LENGTH( input ) /5 )` should use `<=` instead, unless you did want to be less than the "matches required".

Comment: @mareoraft Did you try it out on the sqlfiddle? It still shows the same results with or without <=

Comment: There's nothing in your query that counts the number of matches in the same row. `@limit` counts each row with a match.

Comment: To get the number of occurrences of @string in a field, you use `(LENGTH(input) - LENGTH(replace(input, @string, '')))/LENGTH(@string)`

Comment: Since you're searching for a string that's 4 characters long (when you include one of the spaces around it), the only way you'll get at least length/5 matches is if there's almost nothing else in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a built-in function that counts the occurrences of a string in a column. The workaround is the formula:

```
(CHAR_LENGTH(column) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(column, @string, '')))/CHAR_LENGTH(@string)
```

`replace(column, @string, ''))` returns the column value with all occurrences of `@string` removed. When you subtract that length from the length of the full column, you get the length of all repetitions of the string. Dividing that by the length of the string results in the number of occurrences. So your query should be:

```
SELECT input, response, (CHAR_LENGTH(input) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(input, 'one', '')))/CHAR_LENGTH('one') AS matches
FROM allData
HAVING matches >= CEIL(CHAR_LENGTH(input)/5)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4265e/1)

Comment: Instead of it being, 'one', can it be ' one ', instead? With spaces to the left and right of the word 'one', so that it can match sure that it's a new word, as oppose to it being a part of another word?

Comment: So, for example, if the row contains something like, "xonex", it'll return it too. I only want it to return if it's something like "x one x", with spaces to the left and right of "one".

Comment: What if it contains "one one"? There's no space on the left of the first word, or the right of the second word. You can use a regular expression to match this, but there's no way to count them in MySQL.

Comment: That's why there's never any rows with "one one" in my database. I always add a space to the left and right of my string before inserting it into the database, so it's " one one ". Which is why there's no reason to worry about that. Do you have a solution to my problem, or it's impossible to think up?

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this just in SQL. You need a stored procedure that counts occurrences, or do it in the client language.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to make do with this, then.