# Add spaces to the left and right of a word in string in a SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database

I have a working SELECT statement but there's something I would like to change about it. However, I'm wondering if instead of the word 'one', is it possible to use the word ' one ', instead. With spaces to the left and right of 'one' so that it makes sure that it's not part of another word. So, for example, if the word is something like 'someONE', it wouldn't get selected. Please take a look at my code.

```
SELECT input, (CHAR_LENGTH(input) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(input, 'one', '')))/CHAR_LENGTH('one') AS matches
FROM allData
HAVING matches >= CEIL(CHAR_LENGTH(input)/5)
AND matches = ( 
SELECT MAX( (
(CHAR_LENGTH(input) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(input, 'one', '')))/CHAR_LENGTH('one')
) ) 
FROM allData )
```

I tried using ' one ', instead of 'one', but it returned no results when I did that, when previously, using just 'one', it returned 2 rows of results. Here's a sqlFiddle for anyone who want to test the actual code out for themselves:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/136e3/2

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))

RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 SET i = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN 
  loop_label: LOOP 
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label;  
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT input, (CHAR_LENGTH(input) - CHAR_LENGTH(select regex_replace(input, '[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]', '')))/CHAR_LENGTH('[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]') AS matches
FROM allData
HAVING matches >= CEIL(CHAR_LENGTH(input)/5)
AND matches = ( 
SELECT MAX( (
(CHAR_LENGTH(input) - CHAR_LENGTH(select regex_replace(input, '[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]', '')))/CHAR_LENGTH('[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]')
) ) 
FROM allData )
```

Comment: `matches >= CEIL(CHAR_LENGTH(input)/5)` makes little sense; it means the string must occur once every 5 characters. Any string above 5 characters could never pass this, and a 3 character string (such as the example) would need to make up 60% of all the letters in the string...and the other 40% would mostly need to be minimal word separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using space, I would suggest you to use word boundaries. You are looking for:

```
[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]
```

Comment: So, instead of CHAR_LENGTH(replace(input, 'one', ''), you are saying that I should use CHAR_LENGTH(replace(input, [[:<:]]one[[:>:]]', '') instead?

Comment: Yes.. and you missed a quote in your replace method :)

Comment: I don't think REPLACE supports REGEXs, does it?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work in replace. It threw an error in sqlFiddle.

Comment: @Uueerdo AFAIK it does not support regexes.. but we just want to replace the string with word boundaries so that the select statement will understand it.

Comment: Yes. It threw an error, and it doesn't work. Here. Try it out in the sqlFiddle I provided if you want: SELECT input, (CHAR_LENGTH(input) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(input, '[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]', '')))/CHAR_LENGTH('[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]') AS matches
FROM allData
HAVING matches >= CEIL(CHAR_LENGTH(input)/5)
AND matches = ( 
SELECT MAX( (
(CHAR_LENGTH(input) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(input, '[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]', '')))/CHAR_LENGTH('[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]')
) ) 
FROM allData )

Comment: @jessica can you tell me what your query is trying to do?

Comment: So for example:

Column: input: example row  "what superpower would you have for one day"

^---this would only get selected if there are 8 matches, because 42/5 = 8.4.

42 is the char length of the string above. This should've only been selected from there if there are 8 matches.

Comment: Take it look at this question. It directly corresponds with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704222/selecting-matches-according-to-the-char-length-of-the-strings-in-rows

Comment: I cannot see anything that should error with that query, even if it doesn't give the results desired.

Comment: It threw an error in sqlFiddle half the time, and the other half of the time it doesn't give the results desired. Did you try out the sqlFiddle?

Comment: @Uueerdo jessica is right.. it will throw error..  we are not using regex correcly here.. :)

Comment: @karthikmanchala it is not actually using regex at all, so it should be just as effective (and error free) as any other irrelevant string.

Comment: @jessica you want to select a row only if a particular column has more than 8 matches of a particular word right?

Comment: No. It depends on the char length of the string. For example, a string with char length of 5 or less will need 1 match. Between  5 and 10 with need 2 matches. Between 10 and 15 with need 3. And so on.

Comment: That's where HAVING matches >= CEIL(CHAR_LENGTH(input)/5) comes into play.

Comment: @jessica yes.. 1 thing i am sure about is you cant use regex here :D

Comment: Haha. No. I mean, any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: @jessica [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) would help..

Comment: How am I suppose to use it?

Comment: @jessica nevermind.. just use this [function](https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/) :D

Comment: Just tried using it. It doesn't work. I can't get the SQL part to show up because it's throwing an error or something. I just included the SQL part in my code above, below the slqFiddle link. Please check it out.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm an idiot. Instead of trying to get the char_length of the string in the database, and showing it according to the number of matches, why don't I just get the char_length of the string outside of the database? *facepalms* I upvoted and checked your answer because you shown effort even if it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into [MySQL Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). Most likely, the best option for you is something similar to this...
`WHERE input REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z]+one[^a-zA-Z]+'`

*I say similar because it will not catch inputs that begin or end with the word 'one'. (The pattern in karthik's answer is probably more effective.)*

Comment: Hmmm, that does not incorporate any of my other codes. Please try using that incorporating the rest of my code, and testing it in the sqlFiddle I provided to see if it works or not.

Comment: Since mysql has no regex replace, I don't think what you want is possible without a complex custom stored function. However, the pattern both I and karthik have given should at least ensure all results have at least one "one" word.

Comment: Hmmm. Try this out in the sqlFiddle I provided. It throws an error and actually doesn't work. SELECT input, (CHAR_LENGTH(input) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(input, '[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]', '')))/CHAR_LENGTH('[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]') AS matches FROM allData HAVING matches >= CEIL(CHAR_LENGTH(input)/5) AND matches = ( SELECT MAX( ( (CHAR_LENGTH(input) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(input, '[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]', '')))/CHAR_LENGTH('[[:<:]]one[[:>:]]') ) ) FROM allData )